# Minimax solution for Zero-Sum Game

Tags: game-theory

I try to understand the way to finding the minimax solution to zero-sum game.

The following example is takes from [Wikipedia. Minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax)

[image]

> Wikipedia: The following example of a zero-sum game, where A and B make simultaneous moves, illustrates minimax solutions.Suppose each player has three choices and consider the payoff matrix for A displayed at right. Assume the payoff matrix for B is the same matrix with the signs reversed (i.e. if the choices are A1 and B1 then B pays 3 to A). Then, the minimax choice for A is A2 since the worst possible result is then having to pay 1, while the simple minimax choice for B is B2 since the worst possible result is then no payment.

Question: Why the minimax choice for A is actually A2, the worst possible result is actually A3 (-4), and the worst possible result for B is B3 (+4). In addition the wording "simple minimax choice for B" is very confusing, is it different from the standard minimax choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worst A takes when taking (across the rows):

- A1: -2
- A2: -1
- A3: -4

The minimum loss is A2.

The worst B takes when taking (along the columns):

- B1: -3
- B2: 0
- B3: -4

It is best for B to pick B2.

Does that help? :)

Answer (score 1):

It is A2 because the following. A asks oneself "What is the worst thing that can happen to me if I play A1?" The answer to that is -2. "What is the worst thing that can happen to me if I play A2$" The answer to that is -1. And finally "What is the worst thing that can happen to me if I play A3" The answer to that is -4. Hence, I'm better off in a minimax sense if I play A2. The other thinks the same, her payoffs tho are just the negatives of those above (since one pays them the other receives)

Answer (score 0):

Let consider a matrix consisting of m rows and n columns. The two players A and B know the content of the payout matrix $A$ and the game consists for each player $k=A,B$ in choosing a strategy $ a_ {k, i} \in A$ without knowing the choice of the other.

> Let $A_A=A$ be the payment matrix of player A, so $A_B=-A$: note that $A_A + A_B = 0$ (*zero sum game*).

The choice of a strategy by player A corresponds to the choice of a row, while for player B it corresponds to the choice of a column. Player B will pay player A the sum indicated at the intersection of the row chosen by player A with the column chosen by player B.
Therefore, player B will  desire to minimize the payment due to player A, i.e. player B want to maximize $A_B=-A$. So, player B will try to minimize $A$.
On the other hand, player A desires to maximize the payout received by player B, i.e. player A want to maximize $ A_A = A$ and therefore will try to maximize $A$.
Basically the behavior of the two players is exactly the opposite: player A is called the *maximizing player*, while player B is called the *minimizing player*.

> Symmetrically if player B were given the matrix of the payments he should receive from player A $A_B=A$, then player A would become the minimizing player and player B the maximizing player.

At this point the attention of the two players turns to the same object: the $A$ matrix. Player A tries to maximize $A$, but his control is limited only to choose a row. The same for player B who tries to minimize $A$: his control is limited only to the choice of a column. The two antagonistic players what criteria will adopt?

John von Neumann answered this question using the following criterion: *player A first detects the smallest number of each row and decides to choose the row that contains the largest of the monetary values considered*: in this way he is certain that **his payout will not be less than the value**:

$ \max_i (\min_j a_{i,j})$

whatever player B choices.

*Player B considers the largest number of each column and decides to choose the column that contains the smallest of the numbers considered*: so he is certain that **his loss will not exceed the value**

$ \min_j (\max_j a_{i,j})$

whatever the choice of player A.

What it has just been described represents the definition of **rational behavior** given by John von Neumann and it is commonly referred to as the *principle of minimax choice*.